# Does the sequence of libraries included in HTML head section matters?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web designing, I was trying to create a tooltip but my code was not working, here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

 <!-- bootstrap css files -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
 <script src="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!--Script for toolttip-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            });
</script>
<!--Script for toolttip Ends-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Edit"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But then I made this change and it worked,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<!-- bootstrap css files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--Script for toolttip-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            });
</script>
<!--Script for toolttip Ends-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Edit"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I did was to interchange line 8 and 9, SO my question is, does the sequence in which I include bootstrap JS library ang JQ library matter? and if so why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes... always you need to add first jquery library..

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's Javascript needs jQuery, so you have to load jQuery then Bootstrap's Javascript.

This is noted on the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#plugin-dependencies):

> Also note that all plugins depend on jQuery (this means jQuery must be included **before** the plugin files).

(emphasis by Bootstrap)